# SQL Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'End'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, syntax-error, dynamic-sql

Need help with this SQL Server 2000 procedure. The problem is made difficult because I'm testing procedure via Oracle SQL Developer.

I'm running the procedure to iterate column with new sequence of numbers in Varchar format for those who have null values.

But I keep getting error, so a) I may have done a wrong approach b) syntax is incorrect due to version used. I'm primarily Oracle user.

Error I keep getting: `SQL Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'End'.` which isn't helpful enough to fix it out. The `End` refers to the very last 'End' in the procedure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the Procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OF_AUTOSEQUENCE] @JvarTable Varchar(250), @varColumn Varchar(250), @optIsString char(1), @optInterval int AS
/*
Procedure   OF_AUTOSEQUENCE
Created by  Joshua [Surname omitted]
When        20100902

Purpose     To fill up column with new sequence numbers
Arguments   varTable    - Table name
            varColumn   - Column name
            optIsString - Option: is it string or numeric, either use T(rue) or F(alse)
            optInterval - Steps in increment in building new sequence (Should be 1 (one))

Example script to begin procedure

EXECUTE [dbo].[OF_AUTOSEQUENCE] 'dbo.EH_BrownBin', 'Match', 'T', 1

Any questions about this, please send email to
[business email omitted]
*/

declare
@topseed      int,
@stg_topseed  varchar(100),
@Sql_string   nvarchar(4000),
@myERROR      int,    
@myRowCount   int

set @Sql_string = 'Declare  MyCur CURSOR FOR select ' + @varColumn + ' from ' + @JvarTable + ' where ' + @varColumn + ' is null'
Exec sp_executesql @Sql_string

SET NOCOUNT ON

Begin

  if @optIsString = 'T'
    Begin
      set @Sql_string = 'select top 1 ' + @varColumn + ' from ' + @JvarTable + ' order by convert(int, ' + @varColumn + ') desc' 
      set @stg_topseed =  @Sql_string
      set @topseed = convert(int, @stg_topseed)
    ENd
  else
    Begin
      set @Sql_string = 'select top 1 ' + @varColumn + ' from ' + @JvarTable + ' order by ' + @varColumn + ' desc' 
      set @topseed =  @Sql_string
    ENd
--  SELECT @myERROR = @@ERROR, @myRowCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT
--  IF @myERROR != 0 GOTO HANDLE_ERROR


  open MyCur
  fetch next from MyCur
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    set @topseed = @topseed + @optInterval
    if @optIsString = 'T'
      begin
        set @Sql_string = 'update ' + @JvarTable + ' set ' + @varColumn + ' = cast((' + @topseed + ') as char) where current of ' + MyCur
        exec (@Sql_string)
      ENd
    else
      begin
        set @Sql_string = 'update ' + @JvarTable + ' set ' + @varColumn + ' = ' + @topseed + ' where current of ' + MyCur
        exec (@Sql_string)
      ENd
    fetch next from MyCur
  ENd
--  SELECT @myERROR = @@ERROR, @myRowCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT
--  IF @myERROR != 0 GOTO HANDLE_ERROR

--HANDLE_ERROR:
--print @myERROR

CLOSE MyCur
DEALLOCATE MyCur 

End
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you're missing a `begin` right after the `WHILE`.  You indented like you want a block (multiple statements) in the while loop, and even have a `end` for the `while`, but no `begin`.

make it:

```
...
  open MyCur
  fetch next from MyCur
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  begin --<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<add this
    set @topseed = @topseed + @optInterval
    if @optIsString = 'T'
      begin
        set @Sql_string = 'update ' + @JvarTable + ' set ' + @varColumn + ' = cast((' + @topseed + ') as char) where current of ' + MyCur
        exec (@Sql_string)
      ENd
    else
      begin
        set @Sql_string = 'update ' + @JvarTable + ' set ' + @varColumn + ' = ' + @topseed + ' where current of ' + MyCur
        exec (@Sql_string)
      ENd
    fetch next from MyCur
  ENd
...
```

Comment: Well spotted. Now I have a different error.
<code>SQL Error: Invalid column name 'MyCur'.</code>. Maybe my approach is wrong.

Comment: you need to `FETCH NEXT FROM MyCur INTO @a`.  so, you must declare a local variable @a previously and then then change ...`+ ' where current of ' + MyCur` to ...`+ ' where current of ' + @a`

Comment: The missing `BEGIN` statement could be anywhere in the code prior to the error. I found one missing after a nested if in my own code. Never the less, this answer suggested what to look for.